# Ubuntu 12.04 desktop with no launcher and no shortkeys working

Tags: 12.04, python, launcher, gnome-terminal

I have accidentally uninstalled python 2.7 and python-minimal from my Ubuntu. It gave me an error saying wicd has shut down and there are broken packages.

When I restarted the system, only the desktop is seen. No launcher or any other panels are seen. Even <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is not working to open up the terminal. I have a folder in my desktop which can help in navigating to the file system.

Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing to the text console by hitting Ctrl+Alt+F1. Log in with your username and password. Then type:

```
sudo apt-get install python python-minimal
```

Enter your password again. Confirm the installation with "Y". After the installation is complete, type:

```
sudo reboot
```

The problem should be fixed.

Comment: No, not likely. When you uninstall python all the programs that depend on it are also uninstalled, reinstalling python will not install them back.

Comment: Thanks pille1842. It didt work. As Javier says, some apps needed be install again.. Its fine anyways. Thank you